# Knockout Ajax with Interval show only changed data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have this code:

```
function MyViewModel()
{
  var myviewmodel=this;
  myviewmodel.ajaxData=ko.observableArray([]);


  myviewmodel.init=function()
  {
    updateInterval(function()
    {
      myviewmodel.getData();
    },6000);
  }

  myviewmodel.getData=function()
  {
    myviewmodel.ajaxData([])
    $.get('getData.php')
    .done(function(data)
    {
      if(data.status==='ok' && data.data)
      {
        $.map(data.data,function(f)
        {
          var last_item=new AjaxItem(f);
          myviewmodel.ajaxData.push(last_item);
        })
      }
    })
  }

  function AjaxItem(data)
  {
    var item=this;
    item.id=parseInt(data.id);
    item.name=ko.observable(data.name);
    item.surname=ko.observable(data.surname);
    item.viewed=ko.observable(true);

    setTimeout(function()
    {
       item.viewed(false);
    },600);
  }
}
var vm= new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm)
vm.init();
```

And I view it in this html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
........
<script src="somejs.js"></script>

<style>
.green{
 background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:ajaxData">
      <tr data-bind="css{'green:viewed'}">
       <td data-bind="text:name"></td><td data-bind="text:surname"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</boby>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I do the call I have to refill the array ajaxData and there is some sort of 'blink' when I do that what I want is to find any items changed and show only them.

There are 3 cases of difference:

1. Id exists in but name and surname are different then I want to change the name and surname.
2. Item exists in Javascript does not exist in the data returned from call therefore I want be removed from ajaxData
3. Item does not exist in the returned data therefore I want to be added at the end of ajaxData observable array.

Do you fellows have an Idea how to do that.

NOTE: The problem is HOW to do the comparisons. How I will know that is one returned value exists in the already returned data or not.

Comment: Store a list of `AjaxItem` objects before your Ajax call. Compare the response data, then add, remove or update accordingly.

Comment: The problem is how to do the comparisons.

Comment: See if this fiddle helps: https://jsfiddle.net/Cl3MM/nLjn25ms/ (i did not tested it, you may have to tweak it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your three requirements are exactly what the [Knockout Mapping Plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) will do for you.

But before that, there are several things to fix in your general approach.

First, let's get the Ajax stuff out of your viewmodel. How about an object that collects all your API calls in one place and exposes them as functions?

This exposes `.getData()` (which in turn uses `.get()` internally).

```
var API = {
  get: function (url, params) {
    return $.get(url, params, null, "json").then(function (result) {
      if (result.status === 'ok') return result;
      console.error("Error status for " + url + ": " + result.status, result);
    }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
      console.error("Could not get " + url + ", error is: " + error);
    });
  },
  getData: function(params) {
    return this.get('getData.php', params);
  }
};
```

---

Next, don't call your viewmodels "Viewmodel". That's their purpose, it should not be their name. You seem to have two types of things here, items and a list of items. I don't know what your items *actually* are, so I stuck with the name `Item`, you can choose an even better one. So let's make two constructors:

```
function Item(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = parseInt(data.id);
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.surname = ko.observable(data.surname);
  self.viewed = ko.observable(true);
  setTimeout(function () {
    self.viewed(false);
  }, 600);
}

function ItemList() {
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.observableArray();

  self.init = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ItemList.mapping, self);
  };
  self.load = function () {
    API.getData().done(self.init);
  };
}
```

Note how the `API` gets called which makes the `ItemList` viewmodel much easier to read. Also note how separating `load` and `init` enables you to initialize your viewmodel with data you did not get via Ajax (localStorage maybe?).

You can see how we already call `ko.mapping.fromJS` here. In order to map an incoming object into a functioning viewmodel, the viewmodel properties should be called like the data properties.

Assuming your Ajax response looks like this:

```
{
  status: "ok",
  data: [
    {id: 1, name: "Doctor", surname: "Evil"},
    {id: 2, name: "Austin", surname: "Powers"}
  ]
}
```

There are two properties, `status` and `data`.

- `status` we want to ignore, it's not important for the function of the viewmodel.
- `data` contains a list of objects that should become `Item` instances in our observable array of the same name.

To do this, the mapping plugin needs instructions. We can slap them onto the `ItemList` object for convenience.

```
ItemList.mapping = {
  ignore: ["status"],
  data: {
    key: function (data) {
      return ko.unwrap(data.id);
    },
    create: function (options) {
      return new Item(options.data);
    }
  }
};
```

This tells the mapping plugin not to bother with `status`, but to do two things with the objects in `data`:

- The `key` function will be used to determine the ID of an object, so the mapping plugin knows when an incoming object should be used to update an existing viewmodel. We use the `id` property for that.
- The `create` function will be used to turn the incoming plain objects into `Item` instances.

Now every time `ko.mapping.fromJS` is called on fresh data that came from the server, knockout will cherry-pick existing objects and only update properties that have changed, instead of redrawing the entire list. Missing objects will be removed from the screen, new objects will be added.

---

The view stays the same:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
        <tr data-bind="css: {green: viewed}">
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: surname"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Putting it all together (expand and run the example):

```js
var API = {
  get: function (url, params) {
    return $.get(url, params, null, "json").then(function (result) {
      if (result.status === 'ok') return result;
      console.error("Error status for " + url + ": " + result.status);
    }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
      console.error("Could not get " + url + ", error is: " + error);
    });
  },
  getData: function(params) {
    return this.get('getData.php', params);
  }
};
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

function Item(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = parseInt(data.id);
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.surname = ko.observable(data.surname);
  self.viewed = ko.observable(true);
  setTimeout(function () {
    self.viewed(false);
  }, 600);
}

function ItemList() {
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.observableArray();
  
  self.init = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ItemList.mapping, self);
  };
  self.load = function () {
    API.getData().done(self.init);
  };
}
ItemList.mapping = {
  ignore: ["status"],
  data: {
    key: function (data) {
      return ko.unwrap(data.id);
    },
    create: function (options) {
      return new Item(options.data);
    }
  }
};
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

// Ajax mockup
$.mockjax({
  url: "getData.php",
  responseText: {
    status: "ok",
    data: [
      {id: 1, name: "Doctor", surname: "Evil"},
      {id: 2, name: "Austin", surname: "Powers"}
    ]
  }
});

var vm =  new ItemList();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.load();
setInterval(vm.load, 6000);
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.6.2/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
        <tr data-bind="css: {green: viewed}">
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: surname"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: The problem is that the response may return an err status when something wrong happened. When 'err' is thrown I do not return data or the data returned may contain a string instead of array of objects. How I will handle that?

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle that. Have you tried what my script does in that case? The Ajax mockup that I use in my code should be very easy to modify.